# How to create delay

Tags: c++, windows

I need to create a delay timer without using `Sleep()` from `windows.h` since it will pause current and child threads. So i need a simple delay timer to apply into my program.

Thank you.

Comment: Sleep only pauses the calling thread. What do you mean by a child thread?

Comment: I don't want to sleep the thread. I just want a timer let say count 1 until 3, then the operation start. I use Sleep before but all my threads are sleeping.

Comment: what kind of threads are you using?  Many implementations have a way of suspending thread execution or blocking until signaled to continue processing ...

Comment: @AJG85 im using MFC worker thread. actually i want to generate random integers every 1 sec. i need some kind of looping of perhaps library function to perform this task.

Comment: @Chicko sounds like something a timer could achieve.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Of course that link to MFC CWnd::SetTimer may be over the top if OP is not using MFC.

Answer (score 3):

Polling is a bad idea since it means a busy loop. The normal way to do this on Windows is with a timer. See [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`Sleep` does not affect any other threads. If you find that all your threads are stopped when you call `Sleep`, it means that the sleeping thread has a resource that they are all waiting on. Find out what that resource is, otherwise your program can't possibly work as planned.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a loop and poll the system timer repeatedly. This causes full CPU usage, however - using `Sleep` (either directly or indirectly) is how delays are usually implemented.

Alternatively, you can create an event and call `WaitForSingleObject` with the desired delay. But that's crazy, `Sleep` really does the same thing but better.

Comment: i want to generate random number every 1 sec. so i dont have any object to be attached into a handle.

Comment: Ok, I honestly don't know anymore what you want to achieve. Please explain.

Comment: You want a timer as per my answer.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler you see, when i want to use `WaitForSingleObject`, i need a object handler to be passed in. but my task is clear and simple, just want to create rand number every 1 sec. is `sleep` affect my other threads?

Comment: @David Heffernan yes. i need a counter like 1 until 3 sec, then start my operation. i did sleep(3000) before, but it affect my other threads too.

Comment: @Chicko Bueno It wouldn't have affected your other threads. Most likely it would have made your main thread containing your message loop non-responsive which might be what you saw. Sleep should almost never be used. You need a timer. You even said so in a comment to the Q!

Comment: @Alexander Polling will be identical to sleep except that CPU usage is 100% instead of 0%. Sounds like a terrible idea!

Comment: Oh yes of course - but at that point it was simply not clear what he intended, I thought he just wanted to avoid `Sleep()`. I would delete the response if there were no comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some loop and count the seconds at the same time you have to keep up the message pumping too. This will make ur program responsive.

Why delay? delay is not really good idea. You should think of using synchronization object like mutex, event.